# Voice call in android using OpenSL

Tags: android, audio, voip, opensl

I'm doing a VoIP application for my thesis. I would like to know if someone can help me with this scenario:
I have two threads, AudioThread and AudioSendThread. The first one its the listener that receive the audio-packet throught a DatagramSocket and play it in the phone. The second one its a recorder that grab 20 millisecond of sound and send it to the other device. I have implemented it in java but its really slow, so i decided to try OpenSL, but i dont find any documentation for something like this.

This is the AudioSendThread

```
public class AudioSendThread implements Runnable {
private final static String TAG = "AudioSndThread";
private boolean createdAudioP = false;
private DatagramSocket audioSndSocket;
private String ipAddr;
private byte[] buffer;

public AudioSendThread(Object o){
    this.ipAddr = //getting IpAddress
    audioSndSocket = (DatagramSocket)o;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if(!createdAudioP)
        createdAudioP = createAudioRecorder();
    if(createdAudioP)
        startRecording();
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    while(true){
            byte[] buffer = readAudio(20); //read 20 milliseconds of audio, this is the one i would like to implement in OpenSL
        try {
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName(this.ipAddr), PORT.AUDIO);
            audioSndSocket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

    }
}

public static native void startRecording();
public static native boolean createAudioRecorder();
public static native byte[] readAudio(int millis);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("SoundUtils");
}}
```

And thisone the AudioThread

```
public class AudioThread implements Runnable{
private DatagramSocket audioServSock;

@Override
public void run() {
            createBufferQueueAudioPlayer();
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    Thread audioSndThread = null;
    try {
        this.audioServSock = new DatagramSocket(PORT.AUDIO);
    } catch (SocketException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(true){
        audioSndThread = new Thread(new AudioSendThread(this.audioServSock));
        audioSndThread.start();
    }
            byte[] buffer = new buffer[1500]; //random size
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 1500);
    while(true){
        try {
            audioServSock.receive(packet);
            playAudio(buffer, packet.getLength()); //other method i would like to implement in OpenSL
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return;
        }           
    }
    at.stop();
    at.release();
}

public static native void createBufferQueueAudioPlayer();
public static native void playAudio(byte[] buffer, int length);

/** Load jni .so on initialization */
static {
     System.loadLibrary("native-audio-jni");
}
```

}

The other native methods are taken by the NativeAudio sample of the NDK

Thanks all for any suggestion!

Comment: The Android NDK includes a sample application called `native-audio` which shows how to do recording and playback using OpenSL ES.

Comment: i know it, and i tried to use this sample, but the playback isn't working.. only the mp3 reproducing it it working.

Comment: Here is the ultimate article on low latency streaming on Android: http://createdigitalmusic.com/2013/05/why-mobile-low-latency-is-hard-explained-by-google-galaxy-nexus-still-android-of-choice/

Comment: Did you ever manage to get OpenSL to record calls?

Answer (score 3):

You tried the native-audio sample code supplied with Android-NDK which means you're familiar with JNI calls. Here's a nice blog of Victor Lazzarini which describes his approach to the audio streaming for voice communication using OpenSL ES.

[Android audio streaming with OpenSL ES and the NDK.](http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/android-audio-streaming-with-opensl-es-and-the-ndk/)

You can download the source code from [here.](https://bitbucket.org/victorlazzarini/android-audiotest/src)
Follow the instructions and run it in your device.